# AWS Cognito using Express

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, amazon-cognito

I have used express to create my api routes and I am using AWS Cognito for user authentication.
How can I protect express routes and manage token refresh using AWS Cognito?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [passport strategy npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-cognito) for cognito to simplify the authentication.